# what is the correspondence of OLE of microsoft in openoffice.org

Tags: ms-office, spreadsheet, ole, openoffice.org

I am trying to write an application that is able to export to txt and Excel. I understand that to export to an excel file, you call some OLE stuff. If I want to the computer that does not have Microsoft office installed to receive a spreadsheet export, for example, receive it in OpenOffice spreadsheet ods format, is there any equivalent component in OpenOffice? Or is there any OLE component I can install from Microsoft that allows program call to export to xls / xlsx format(without my computer having to install Office)? For example an unactivated Office?

Comment: LibreOffice Calc can save as .csv or .xlsx or .xls without any special installation required.  Or perhaps you are asking about using [-convert-to](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/) on a command line?  Or [writing a macro](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Writing_Macros) to automatically use LibreOffice to open and export a file?  I'm afraid I do not know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to write a C++ / Java program, that will extract a certain table or view, and export to a xls / ods file, what are the external libraries required?